# Javascript allure-results for jest-allure specify the out directory

Tags: javascript, allure

How to specify an output directory for allure-results when using jest-allure, eg reports/allure-result.

jest.config.js

```js
{
  ..., 
  setupFilesAfterEnv: [
    'jest-allure/dist/setup'
  ],

  reporters: [
    'default',
    'jest-junit',
    'jest-allure',
  ],
 ...
}
```

Comment: have tried with no luck

reporters: [
    'default',
    'jest-junit',
    ['jest-allure', { resultsDir: "reports/allure-results" } ]
  ]

Answer (score 3):

add to jest.config.json testSetup.js

```
  setupFilesAfterEnv: [
    'jest-allure/dist/setup',
    '<rootDir>/testSetup.js'
  ],
```

add one line to testSetup.js

```
reporter.allure.setOptions({ targetDir: 'reports/allure-results' });
```

This has been tested and works

Comment: I know it's been a while this question was answered but thanks for your answer. I was looking for this. 

I tried this one but getting this: 

Property 'allure' is private and only accessible within class 'Reporter'

I wonder if this is a recent change in the library or were you able to get it working with latest version (0.1.3) as well?